# Using MongoDB with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to use mongodb-promise to access the MongoDB server, but i'm getting the following error:

```
{ Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/Repositories/learn-express/node_modules/mongodb-promise/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js:15:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

I'm using the last version of the package which is 0.0.4. Does anyone knows any package to deal with MongoDB using promises?

Answer (score 0):

The mongodb-promise package is few years old, from the time MongoDB native Node.js driver did not support Promises. Just use the native driver, it has promise support now. More details in the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)